# How do I find the string 'NULL' in a string?

Tags: sql

I want to find the string `NULL` or `NULL` surrounded by any characters except when the next letter is `O` or `A` (i.e. `NULLO` and `NULLA` are ok).  I have come up with the below so far, but it doesn't quite do what I want:

```
DECLARE @VAR VARCHAR(255)
SET @VAR = 'NULL'
SELECT @VAR WHERE @VAR LIKE '%NULL[^OA]'
```

Comment: please show your required inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go for:

```
 REPLACE(REPLACE(@VAR,'NULLA',''),'NULLO','') LIKE '%NULL%'
```

Comment: but if you have NULLOXXX, it will return XXX. Is this expected?

Comment: @Diego: a `LIKE` expression does not return a string, it is a test so it returns an SQL boolean value (true, false or null). Here `'xxx' like '%NULL%'`` will return false, which is what OP expects IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
DECLARE @VAR VARCHAR(255)
SET @VAR = 'NULL'
SELECT @VAR WHERE @VAR LIKE '%NULL%'
AND @VAR NOT LIKE '%NULL0%'
AND @VAR NOT LIKE '%NULLA%'
```

Answer (score 1):

this seems to have done the trick for me:
select * from nulls_table where null_field not like 'NULL[OA]%'

I created a table with these values:

```
ANULL
ONULL
NULLA
NULLO
ANULLA
NULL
NULLOXXX
```

and the select returns

```
ANULL
ONULL
ANULLA
NULL
```

it eliminated NULLA, NULLO and NULLOXXX which seems to be what the OP wants 
(find the string NULL or NULL surrounded by any characters except when the next letter is O or A )

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CHARINDEX`

```
SELECT @VAR WHERE CHARINDEX(@VAR , 'NULL') > 0
```

OR

```
SELECT @VAR WHERE CHARINDEX('NULL' , @VAR) > 0
```